# Unable to run react app and java backend on single port

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, tomcat, servlets

I am currently developing an single-page web app using React.js and backend using servlet according to the requirements for my internship project. I wanted to know as to how can I make my react front end and java backend run together on tomcat server inside my IDE? I am using eclipse IDE and Tomcat 8.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the webpack server to run the react app and tomcat to run your java backend. What you will have to do is serve the react app through your Java backend itself instead of serving your react app from another server

Comment: Thats what i want to do but I dont know where to add and configure my tomcat so that they both run together on the same port

Comment: You will have to run npm build and serve the build folder from your java server